# Why does f-string literal not work here, whereas %()s formatting does?

Tags: python, flask, string-formatting, flask-wtforms

I am trying to format my validator message with the min/max values in the actual validator.

Here's my Flask Form:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    example = IntegerField(label=('Integer 0-10'),
              validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=10, message="must be between %(min)s and %(max)s!")])
```

Using `message="must be between %(min)s and %(max)s!"` gives me the expected output:

```
must be between 0 and 10!
```

Whereas using `message=f"must be between {min} and {max}!"` gives me the output:

```
must be between <built-in function min> and <built-in function max>!
```

How can I use f-string formatting for my validator message? Is this something related to f-string evaluating at run-time? I don't fully understand the concept behind it, I just know it's the preferred way to string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"must be between %(min)s and %(max)s!"` is a string literal that Flask will later perform a search-and-replace on, while `f"must be between {min} and {max}!"` is a simpler and more efficient way to say `"must be between " + str(min) + " and " + str(max) + "!"`. That evaluates to the string you described.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so there is merit in using the old string format methods as opposed to only using f-string? (for cases like this?)

Comment: Yes, they serve different needs, even though they're visually similar.

Answer (score 1):

The f-string literal is evaluated *immediately*, before being passed to `IntegerField`.

```
>>> foo = 3
>>> print(f'{foo}')
3
```

The other string contains *literal* `%(...)` substrings which are
used later with the `%` operator.

```
>>> print("%(foo)s")
%(foo)s
>>> print("%(foo)s" % {'foo': 3})
3
```

Comment: So for a use case like my form would you recommend I just stick with %s string formatting so I don't have to declare my validator arguments separately?

Comment: I would. Basically, you are just passing a literal string as an argument, which *can't* be changed depending on variable values in the current scope.

Comment: (Also, I don't know if it's possible for the end points of the `NumberRange` to change during the life time of the field; a hard-code string would not be updated to reflect such a change.)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare such variables, like

```py
min = 1
max = 2
print(f"must be between {min} and {max}!")
```

But please consider to use somewhat different variable names to not shadow builtin functions.

---

Ok, I see it now, you wanted to use that as a kind of string template.